# how to implement checkbox in react (checked and unchecked functionality)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement checkbox in react but I am facing a issue while checking and uncheck of checkbox.

I tried to implement `onchange` handler .

```
onChange={() => {
                    // first approch
                    //  i.checked = !i.checked;
                    // setObj({ ...i});

                    // second approach
                    setObj({ ...i, checked: !i.checked });
                    setTimeout(ab, 2000);
                  }}
```

so I used two approach

In First approach i changed the `toggle the checked` property and then create new `reference` **which is working fine**

```
 i.checked = !i.checked;
   setObj({ ...i});
```

In second approach I created a new object or reference with `toggle of checked property` **but this is not working why**

```
{ ...i, checked: !i.checked }
```

why my first and second approach is different ?

here is my code

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-fire-cxp9c?file=/src/child.js:362-666

```
import React from "react";
export default function Child({ data, ab }) {
  const [obj, setObj] = React.useState(null);

  return (
    <>
      {data &&
        data.map((i, idx) => {
          return (
            <ul key={idx}>
              <li>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={i.checked}
                  onChange={() => {
                    // first approch
                    //  i.checked = !i.checked;
                    // setObj({ ...i});

                    // second approach
                    setObj({ ...i, checked: !i.checked });
                    setTimeout(ab, 2000);
                  }}
                />
                {i.label}
              </li>
              {i.childrens && i.childrens.length > 0 ? (
                <Child data={i.childrens} ab={ab} />
              ) : null}
            </ul>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```

any suggestion ...!!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so mixing the state and props makes it a little messy. I did some refactoring and added in a little recursion for the tree of nested values you're using. I added comments above the changes I made.

```
var data = [/* your array of data */]


// recursive function to find the value in the tree
const setChecked = (data, label) => {
  if (!data || data.length === 0) return [];
  // grab the first element
  const [current, ...rest] = data;

  // if it's found, plop the element back into place with
  // check changed and dump in the rest of the elements
  if (current.label === label) {
    return [
      {
        ...current,
        checked: !current.checked,
        childrens: current.childrens.map((child) => ({
          ...child,
          checked: !current.checked
        }))
      },
      ...rest
    ];
  }

  // re-slot the element and recursively move
  // through the remaining siblings
  return [
    {
      ...current,
      childrens:
        current.childrens.length > 0
          ? setChecked(current.childrens, label)
          : current.childrens
    },
    ...setChecked(rest, label)
  ];
};

export default function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(data1);

  const handleChange = (data) => {
    setState(setChecked(state, data.label));
  };

  const ab = () => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(state));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Child data={state} ab={ab} handleChange={handleChange} />
    </div>
  );
}

// added the onChange handler to lift the state to the parent
export default function Child({ data, ab, onChange }) {
  return (
    <>
      {data &&
        data.map((i, idx) => {
          return (
            <ul key={idx}>
              <li>
                <input
                  type="checkbox"
                  checked={i.checked}
                  onChange={() => {
                    onChange(i);
                    setTimeout(ab, 2000);
                  }}
                />
                {i.label}
              </li>
              {i.childrens && i.childrens.length > 0 ? (
                <Child data={i.childrens} ab={ab} onChange={onChange} />
              ) : null}
            </ul>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I totally agree  your point.but every senior developer said make reusable  component correct ? and event handler should be in same component ...if we move handlers to parent.then there dependency of parent component with child component

Comment: it there any better design ?

Comment: `in setChecked` function you are not checking in parent `childrens object`..it is only checking `one level`

Comment: last one question if some gave this problem to you.which approach you will choose `parent child` (form child you send click handlers to parent). or you create separate component `reusable component ` having click handlers also

Comment: @user5711656 1) The component _is reusable_. 2) You never said checking the parent checks the children. I've edited the answer. 3) I solved your problem. If you don't like the solution, don't use it. If you had provided the parameters you had in your head in the actual question, I'd have solved it that way.

Comment: @sorry actually i am beginner in react , that why I am asking what is better approch

Comment: @user5711656 No apology necessary. Your code was pretty close. The more you use it, the more obvious the "better approach" will be for any given situation. Keep up the good work!

Comment: last it would be great if you answer that mean same `why we need event handler on parent` so every time when I am using the child component i want to define on parent event handler. can we go with some `custom hoooks` ??

Comment: I did that because your state was in the parent, so I like maintaining all of the state there. If your child component held the state vs getting it as a prop, I'd have put the handler there. I don't like having the state split like that. I think it makes things confusing, because the state is still just rendering checkboxes. An alternative is having it all one component with a useEffect hook fetching the data and updating state there, e.g. `useEffect(async ()=> { setState(await api.get('/my-data')) }, []})`

Comment: @user5711656 see edits to this answer. I missed a buncha stuff.